# a is a numerical vector and b is logical. what is suma[b]

Tags: r, indexing, subset

Let a <- c (3, 4, 7, 8) and b <- c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), what will be the output for the R expression sum(a[b]). Answer is 7, But how?

Comment: Because that's how R works. What part don't you understand?

Comment: Check the output of `which(c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE))`. `a` is being subset according to that.

Comment: Using the logical vector `b` as index for `a` means selecting the elements from `a` for which `b` is TRUE.

Comment: OR try typing `a[b]` to see what is being summed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R, a vector (`a` in your question) can be subset with a logical index vector (`b` in your question). If the corresponding members are `TRUE` in the logical vector, the elements (of `a`) are retained.

```
a = c (3, 4, 7, 8)
b = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)

a[b]
#[1] 3 4
```

`a[b]` will retain only the first two elements of `a` because only those values are `TRUE` in `b`. When you `sum` `3`  and `4`, it is `7`

If you give the "[" function a vector which is shorter than the vector being subset, you may get results that are surprising (and no warnings will appear):

```
a[ b[1:3] ]
[1] 3 4 8 # the fourth item in `a` appears because the logical vector is "recycled"
```

Comment: Thank you.. This helped.. I am new at R, so now its clear

Comment: @d.b. Your answer is not an accurate description of logical indexing because it omits the very important (and dangerous) case where logical indices are used which are of different length than the vector being subset. Look at the output from `a[ b[1:3] ]` to see the "danger". Note that no warnings are being given which I would have expected when recycling is present. (I'm not downvoting and will delete this comment if you amend your answer.)